# Material dialog overlay changes

Tags: css, angular-material, modal-dialog, overlay

When using the Angular material dialog i want to move the scrollbar from inside the dialog to the overlay. If i inspect the overlay in HTML i see that it has the following css on it:
[image]

I want to set pointer-events to auto and add a overflow-y: auto as well but i cant seem to access the class in my css. Does anyone know if / how we can change the overlay in a dialog?

Code:

```
modalConfig: MatDialogConfig = {
panelClass: 'custom-dialog',
```

CSS:

```
.custom-dialog {
  min-width: 860px;
  max-width: 860px;
  height: max-content;

  .cdk-overlay-container,
  .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
  }
}
```

p.s. tried ::ng-deep but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I had a similar problem, I was trying to access class names in the dialog CSS. What worked for me was using `::ng-deep` and `!important` as well. Also try when adding the `::ng-deep` property to add them on top of your CSS file as individual rules rather than nested.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick! Shame that even the built-in backdropClass doesn't target this either.